# Different icons for files with same extension but different content?

Tags: .net, file, windows-7, icons

I have associated a certain xml-based file-type of mine (.xmlentity) to my app (.net) and I would like to have different icons based on content (root element name) of these files.

`<note xmlns="mynamespace"></note>` should have one kind of icon and

`<notebook xmlns="mynamespace"></notebook>` should have another.

Is this possible somehow without having different file-extensions?

Its okey if its only working on Windows 7.

Comment: Visual Studio does this with .SLN files (different icon for ones created in VS2008 vs ones created in VS2010). Not sure what the mechanism is, though.

Comment: Related but not the same: http://superuser.com/q/317885/13889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Icon Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28VS.85%29.aspx). It is implemented as a shell extension. Unfortunately, MSDN does not give any icon-handler-specific sample code, but at least this article describes requirements for such shell extension. This article also can be useful: [Creating Shell Extension Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144067%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. One icon for one filetype. However I have seen programs create a preview by plugging into the shell (Windows Photo Viewer is a basic example of this. "Trackmania" also has preview screenshots of its data files)

[Shell Preview Host on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144143%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: It's definitely possible because Visual Studio shows different icons for .SLN files created with VS2008 or VS2010. Exactly how it works, I don't know.

Comment: I agree that it should be possible. On my XP system an .xml file that is in fact an Excel file is shown with the Excel icon even though .xml is associated with a different application. So there seems to be a way the make the icon depend on the file's content. I have however no idea how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering about this and found the answer in this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't leave just one-link- answers. Explain how the question can be solved.